# Utilize the Facebook SDK Login (iOs/Android) for being logged into Facebook @ Web?

Tags: iphone, android, facebook

Straight Forward:

- User logs into my iPhone/Android App with Facebook SDK  [so i got an id and authtoken for that user]
- ... functionality using the FB SDK and much more ...
- **I open a WebView inside my pp  and load the facebook profile of an other user, but in this webview im NOT logged in.**

Is there a possibility, to utilize my login (id/authtoken) from the SDK to get the user automatically logged in inside the webview?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS you can use single sign on, see https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk, scroll down to 'Single Sign On' section with it's description.

This is not a direct solution but perhaps it could help.